# Update records in intermediate table in Codeigniter

Tags: sql-update, many-to-many, codeigniter-3

In my codeigniter3 project, I have 3 tables with many-to-many relationship:

table 1: jobposts (id, title, desc)

table 2: locationitems (id, name)

Table 3: jobpostlocation (jobpost_id, locationitem_id)

Questions: How do I build SQL query to UPDATE records in in jobpostlocation table, when I update jobposts table?

SQL query statement is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    $jobposts = array('title' => $title,'desc' => $desc, );
    $this->db->where('id',$idNo);
    $this->db->update('jobposts',$arrayName);

    $jobpostlocation = array('locationitem_id' => $locationitem_id );
    $this->db->where('jobpost_id',$idNo);
    $this->db->update('jobposts',$jobpostlocation);
```

Comment: I want to update data in table: jobpostlocation because it is intermediate table.